# HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error: name expected at the position 7 of 'struct<`$date`:string>' but '`' is found

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to read a JSON file with AWS Athena.
I crawled it with AWS Glue Crawler and it worked fine but when I try to do a select on the table what I get is the following error:

> HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error: name expected at the position 7 of 'struct' but '$' is found.

I'm aware that the issue is related to the `$` symbol in the struct but I'm wondering if there is any way to overcome this issue or the only way is to write a new file without the $ symbol.

Here an example of the rows that I trying to read.

```
{"_id":"abc123-abc123-abc123-abc123-abc123","lastModifiedDateTime":{"$date":"2022-02-30T22:22:22.310Z"},
"createdDateTime":{"$date":"2016-03-30T19:36:22.310Z"},"user":{"emailAddress":"abcd123@abc.co.uk","brandId":1},
"optIn":{"campaignChannels":[],"campaignCategories":[]}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Are you using AWS Neptune as the data source connector? Even if you don't, maybe this [was forums thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=863010) answers your question *"This is a bug in our parser and we are actively working on a fix... We do not have a timeline right now. (2018)"* I checked all the [releases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases.html), none of them mention anything about `$` :\